# Redux, React state update and re-render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, redux

1. How exactly re-rendering of the components happen if there is a new state object returned from the redux reducer..?
2. Are there any optimisation techniques used by react to minimalize the rendering of components ..?

Comment: Try reading the [docs here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect a component to the redux store, and you map the redux state to props, if a state changes into a new state, the component re-renders. Just like when you pass a state to a child component and that state changes.